# JSP spitting out errors, i think it's due to structure?

Tags: java, html, jsp, ms-access

I am now working pretty quick on this JSP and feel like I am learning pretty quick on this JSP Business.

But I can't help think that this isn't right? I have tried it under my locathost and I am getting problems when it spits it out over my browser. So I feel like I have structured it wrong, but to be honest,; can't workout out where I have gone wrong, I have been doing JSP for about 5 hours so please give me the benefit of the doubt.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" import="java.sql.*"%>
</head>
<body>

<!-- BELOW IS DATABASE CONNECTION SET UP -->
<% 
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:database11"); 
// END OF  DATABASE CONNECTION SET UP 
// START OF TESTING 

String mysql="select * from hotels";
Statement s=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rst=s.executeQuery(mysql);

out.println("<table border='1' width='70%'>");
out.println("<tr>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("NameofPlace") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("NameofPlace") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("Country") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("PricePerNight") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("MaximumPersons") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("StarRating") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='20%'>" + rst.getString ("Description") + "</td>");
out.println("</tr>");

while (rst.next()) {

// Column Details of hotels

out.println("<tr>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("NameofPlace") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("NameofPlace") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("Country") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("PricePerNight") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("MaximumPersons") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("StarRating") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='20%'>" + rst.getString ("Description") + "</td>");
out.println("</tr>");
}

out.println("</table>");


rst.close();
con.close();

%>

</body>
</html>
```

If there is anything that I have done wrong then please tell me as I can imagine it is going to be very neat, well-structured or perfect.

If your curious on what I am doing, then see my previous post earlier this morning: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10485667/university-jsp-booking-project#comment13551068_10485667

But why is it not working, any help is extremely appreciated!?

My Errors:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Exception in JSP: /0906055/index.jsp:24

21: 
22: out.println("<table border='1' width='70%'>");
23: out.println("<tr>");
24: out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("NameofPlace") + "</td>");
25: out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("NameofPlace") + "</td>");
26: out.println("<td width='10%'>" +  rst.getString ("Country") + "</td>");
27: out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("PricePerNight") + "</td>");


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:491)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:774)
    org.apache.jsp._0906055.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:108)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:371)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

root cause

java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid cursor state
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLGetDataString(Unknown Source)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getDataString(Unknown Source)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
    sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcResultSet.getString(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jsp._0906055.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:68)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:371)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/5.5.35 logs.
```

Comment: Keep the amount of code in the JSP pages to a minimum.  Call methods in "real" classes instead.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Sorry to be a pain, but do you mind elaborating a little bit for me as this is all new to me..

Comment: @duffymo So I can just call it in similar to how Shorthand PHP works on say; Wordpress?

Comment: I know that, it's just as an example on how it works, so basically working in separating jsp document's to then pull in together to make one big html document..

Comment: It's a very bad example.  Where did you get it?  Find a better tutorial of you want to learn it pretty quick.

Comment: Most of this is actually taken from my tutor's tutorials on what to do. *sigh*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the fixed issue, after looking at my code, I had to the top area and was repeating the same details. Which is what made it repeat and sign off loads of errors.

I know there are some people who know JSP Fluently and will say this is bad practice; (which is what I have just learned, so I urge you not to code like this. However - for future reference and for anyone who might be in my shoes.

Here is the answer and finished code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" import="java.sql.*"%>
</head>
<body>

<!-- BELOW IS DATABASE CONNECTION SET UP -->
<% 
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:webapps"); 
// END OF  DATABASE CONNECTION SET UP 
// START OF TESTING 

String mysql="select * from hotels";
Statement s=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rst=s.executeQuery(mysql);

out.println("<table border='1' width='70%'>");
out.println(" <tr>");
out.println(" <td width='10%'><b>Name of Place</b></td>");
out.println(" <td width='10%'><b>Country</b></td>");
out.println(" <td width='10%'><b>Price Per Night</b></td>");
out.println(" <td width='10%'><b>Maximum Persons</b></td>");
out.println(" <td width='10%'><b>Star Rating</b></td>");
out.println(" <td width='10%'><b>Description</b></td>");
out.println(" </tr>");

while (rst.next()) {

// Column Details of hotels

out.println(" <tr>");

out.println(" <td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("NameofPlace") + "</td>");
out.println(" <td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("Country") + "</td>");
out.println(" <td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("PricePerNight") + "</td>");
out.println(" <td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("MaximumPersons") + "</td>");
out.println(" <td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("StarRating") + "</td>");
out.println(" <td width='20%'>" + rst.getString ("Description") + "</td>");
out.println(" </tr>");
}

out.println("</table>");


rst.close();
con.close();

%>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're learning from a very, very old source.  The style you're using went out in the late 1990s.  *No one* writes JSPs that way anymore.

The idea is that database access should not be done by a JSP.

You need to learn a lot more about JDBC as well.

You're using an ODBC data source that has no notion of where the Access database you're using is.  Remember that the JSP code executes on the server and creates HTML that is sent to the browser.

I'd recommend using a DSN-less URL for your Access connection:

http://www.jroller.com/sjivan/entry/dsn_less_jdbc_connection_to

I'd make that connection in a servlet.

I'd get Hans Bergsten's O'Reilly book on JSPs and start learning from that.  It showed the proper way to do things years ago.

Update:

```
Invalid cursor state
```

This happened because you tried to access the ResultSet outside the loop.  I've changed your code to fix it.  See if this helps.  Study the JDBC tutorial from Oracle before you go further.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java" import="java.sql.*" errorPage="" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" import="java.sql.*"%>
</head>
<body>

<!-- BELOW IS DATABASE CONNECTION SET UP -->
<% 
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:database11"); 
// END OF  DATABASE CONNECTION SET UP 
// START OF TESTING 

String mysql="select * from hotels";
Statement s=con.createStatement();
ResultSet rst=s.executeQuery(mysql);

out.println("<table border='1' width='70%'>");

while (rst.next()) {

// Column Details of hotels

out.println("<tr>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("NameofPlace") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("NameofPlace") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("Country") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("PricePerNight") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("MaximumPersons") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='10%'>" + rst.getString ("StarRating") + "</td>");
out.println("<td width='20%'>" + rst.getString ("Description") + "</td>");
out.println("</tr>");
}

out.println("</table>");


rst.close();
con.close();

%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is just the requirement's of my university, I know it is outdated, as this module was Actually written in 2005! This is typical university standards, (third-year complete and utter bullshit, but I need to pass it!) It is all done locally as well, there is no need to upload to the server..

Comment: What school?  Why should a university be concerned about low-level things like how to write JSPs?  Where are the high level concepts, like data structures, networking, etc.?

Comment: My university is Anglia Ruskin - SHOCK. I figured they should be teaching us something more up tot date, But I guess there is nothing I can do, I am trying as much as I can to adjust.

I will look into this servlet's. I'm guessing I write the code in different documents and call them in, is that correct?

Comment: Did you try the correction I posted?  Do that first before anything else.

Comment: I tried your correction and it was your correction that made me discover the answer, just where my reputation is below 100 i have to wait another 4 hours before I post the answer!. (so that's why I do not want to up your post). But seriously Thank you very much duffy!

couldn't have done it without you, just one step to getting this out of the way so I never have to touch badly coded JSP again :)

Comment: I think you can accept answers now, even if you can't vote them up.  They're two separate things.

Answer (score 0):

What error messages are you getting? That might be a big clue to telling us what the problem is!

I do see one error: Your first block of rst.getString's is done BEFORE the first rst.next. You don't have a record in the buffer until you do the first rst.next, so there are no strings to get. Perhaps you're thinking that the first record is available before you do next()? It's not. The first next() you do gets you the first record.

There are also the minor points that in both your record dumps you get "NameofPlace" twice. And the sum of your td widths is only 80%. It should total 100% -- td percentages are relative to the width of the table, not the whole screen. (That won't give you an error, though. The browser just guesses at what you might mean.)

Comment: yeah sorry, I should of probably stated that the  second 'NameofPlace' second one is just a filler, while i sort out attachments in my database - and the td width's aren't important as I knew the HTML would adjust for now, (sorry again for not mentioning in the main post!)  

I have updated the main post with errors, I hope that helps, trying to be as co-operative as possible...